# ASA 5505 - Outside IPs required for VPN Tunnel?

Tags: vpn, firewall, cisco, routing, cisco-asa

I've set up a Site-Site VPN and it seems the config is fine as the other site can establish the tunnel fine. The problem I have is that my side never tries to bring the tunnel up.

Ping/telnet results in a timeout and looking in the logs phase1 is never attempted. The only way I can make it attempt to come up is by adding my outside network (as well as inside) to the local network in the vpn config.

Does anyone have any idea what I might have wrong in the config or how I can debug further?

Comment: Can you provide the `packet-tracer` output of traffic that should get the tunnel to build?

Comment: ASDM and VPN wizard...

Answer (score 0):

This can happen if you forget the a NAT Exempt statement.  Consider the standard L2L IPSEC VPN:

```
Router 1: (Pseudocode)
interface inside
    ip address 10.1.0.1/24
interface outside
    ip address 1.2.3.4/24

nat exempt 10.1.0.0/24 to 10.2.0.0/24
pnat 10.1.0.0/24 to 1.2.3.4
ipsec protect 10.1.0.0/24 to/from 10.2.0.0/24 via 1.2.3.5 with PSK abcdef

Router 2:
interface inside
    ip address 10.2.0.1/24
interface outside
    ip address 1.2.3.5/24

nat exempt 10.2.0.0/24 to 10.1.0.0/24
pnat 10.2.0.0/24 to 1.2.3.5
ipsec protect 10.1.0.0/24 to/from 10.2.0.0/24 via 1.2.3.4 with PSK abcdef
```

if you do not include the nat exempt statements, the traffic will get natted prior to evaluation of IPsec, and will be evaluated against the protect acls as `from 1.2.3.4 to 10.2.0.100`, which would not match.